# I am getting a "patient successfully updated" message after updating a object but values stay the same in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sorry i really didn't know how to phrase the question any better but here is my problem:

when i try to update or create a patient object in my rails application the values are not getting sent through to the model, because when i try to create a new patient i get validation errors that i put in place sating i have to enter values (which i did), and when i update an existing patient object the values don't change even though i get the message of "successfully updated patient"

any ideas why that might be?

it used to work fine and i didn't change anything in the patient controller or model for it to stop working?

if you need any code from me please just let me know what u need.

controller create and update code:

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :require_user
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def new
    @patient = Patient.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @patient }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @patient = Patient.new(params[:patient])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @patient.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@patient, :notice => 'Patient was successfully created.') }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @patient.update_attributes(params[:patient])
        format.html { redirect_to(@patient, :notice => 'Patient was successfully updated.') }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

server Log:

```
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update", "authenticity_token"=>"7ypFp3DhLokjvqau06+EOOoEU2T/7UmU5OaAZuGxC1M=", "id"=>"4", "patient"=>{"occupation"=>"nothing", "blood_type"=>"O+", "next_of_kin"=>"mo man", "address"=>"arcklow", "m_name"=>"gfjhgjgfj", "date_of_first_admission(1i)"=>"2006", "tel_number"=>"45345435", "weight"=>"85.0", "date_of_first_admission(2i)"=>"3", "f_name"=>"Allan ", "date_of_first_admission(3i)"=>"3", "mobile_number"=>"43534543", "universal_ID"=>"bebo", "sex"=>"Female", "medical_history"=>"Wrist is", "height"=>"187.0", "family_history"=>"", "bmi"=>"15", "allergies"=>"", "date_of_birth(1i)"=>"1986", "date_of_birth(2i)"=>"8", "email"=>"allandx@gmail.com", "current_medication"=>"ibrufen", "date_of_birth(3i)"=>"17", "l_name"=>"Dixon"}}

WARNING: Can't mass-assign these protected attributes: occupation, blood_type, next_of_kin, address, m_name, date_of_first_admission(1i), tel_number, weight, date_of_first_admission(2i), f_name, date_of_first_admission(3i), mobile_number, universal_ID, sex, medical_history, height, family_history, bmi, allergies, date_of_birth(1i), date_of_birth(2i), email, current_medication, date_of_birth(3i), l_name


  [4;35;1mPatient Load (0.1ms)[0m   [0mSELECT "patients".id FROM "patients" WHERE ("patients"."email" = 'allandx@gmail.com' AND "patients".id  4) LIMIT 1[0m
  [4;36;1mPatient Load (0.1ms)[0m   [0;1mSELECT "patients".id FROM "patients" WHERE ("patients"."universal_ID" = 'bebo' AND "patients".id  4) LIMIT 1[0m
  [4;35;1mPatient Load (0.1ms)[0m   [0mSELECT "patients".id FROM "patients" WHERE ("patients"."l_name" = 'Dixon' AND "patients".date_of_birth = '1986-08-17' AND "patients".f_name = 'Allan ' AND "patients".tel_number = 45345435 AND "patients".id  4)
```

model code:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base

  #patient can have many apointments and vistis
  has_many :appointments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :visits, :dependent => :destroy

  # adding the photo as an attribute to patient 
  attr_accessible :photo
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "200x200>" }

  # validate  that fields are not blank
  validates_presence_of(:f_name, :l_name, :tel_number, :address)

  # validate that fields are numeric
  validates_numericality_of(:height, :weight, :bmi, :tel_number)

  #v alidate uniqueness of fields and users
  validates_uniqueness_of(:email, :universal_ID)
  validates_uniqueness_of(:l_name, :case_sensitve => false, :scope => [:date_of_birth, :f_name, :tel_number], :message => "User already existsts")

  #validate Email is right format
  validates_format_of(:email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :message => "Dosen't look like a real email address, please try again")

  #validate the date of birth
  validates_inclusion_of(:date_of_birth, :in => Date.civil(1900, 1, 1) .. Date.today, :message => "Must be between the year 1900 and today")


end
```

thanks

Comment: can you post your params hash from your server log?

Comment: i checked in firebug and the params sent are the right ones, i posted the server log info in the question.

Comment: the values in the server log are the correct ones as well, however as you see there is an interesting Warning message, is this the problem? what is this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 # adding the photo as an attribute to patient 
 attr_accessible :photo
```

Here is your problem maybe you wanted `attr_accesor` instead of `attr_accesible` ?

Comment: whats the difference? i tried putting in all the attribute in the atter_accessible and it seemed to work.

Im guessing atter_accessible makes only them values accessible and atter accesor is adding an attribute?

Comment: It specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via mass-assignment, such as new(attributes), update_attributes(attributes), or attributes=(attribute)

Comment: i keep running in to loads of little problems like this, learning a new language isnt as easy as i thought it was :)

thanks for your help